# vega-lite: Adjustable selection?

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega

Is there a way to get a adjustable selection in vega-lite?

I found this example but I think this is made with plain vega.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vega-Lite does not provide any way to create an interval selection with a size that is adjustable by clicking and dragging on the edges.

Available configuration properties are listed in the [interval selection docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html#interval). The only configurable interactions are `translate`, which enables moving the selection by clicking and dragging, and `zoom`, which enables changing the selection's size by zooming on its interior; both of these are True by default.

Here is a simple specification that lets you see the effect of these configurations ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegM4AcBWABmIDoBjXANxAF8AaEAWwmQGsM2BTWJ3bqm4UoASwD2AO3igARskS4AFjJBQAnvm4ZRkqN2TUI6Jt0kVxYXQHNc8ANogAHiAC6TAF7jxzeFAXcTP4Qkrio0Npw-ojcdIwgZhZWktaqLgggAGaigmAYkPogQZqRatzM+OLIxvRM6qrZuRj4yKIU2sVaGACOiCFiMGLU2nFMAO6iYFAqcAAspHRAA)):

```json
{
  "data": {"url": "data/sp500.csv"},
  "mark": "area",
  "selection": {
    "brush": {
      "type": "interval",
      "encodings": ["x"],
      "zoom": true,
      "translate": true
    }
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "width": 400
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if there were some built-in support for resizing options.  It would seem possible to roll-your-own by drawing draggable resize marks and using that to initialize the interval selection.